# Having trouble moving files in bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                         

for i in {0..9} ;
do
    mkdir -p "d$i "
    for j in {0..9};
    do
        if [ -e "./f$i$j.txt" ];
        then
            echo 'Moving!'
            mv    "./f$i$j.txt" "./d$i/f$j.txt"
        fi
    done
done
```

The above code is intended to search the current working directory for any files of name f##.txt where # is a number and arrange them into directories such that fAB.txt becomes dA/fB.txt. As far as I can tell it should work however I get the below error running the code.

```
Moving!
mv: cannot move './f48.txt' to './d4/f8.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The directories you create all have a trailing space in their name, which means if you enter the `if` statement, you are actually renaming every file, not moving it into another directory.

Comment: That error aside, `mv "$PWD/f$i$j.txt" "$PWD/d$i/f$j.txt"` is sufficient; you don't to run `mv` twice.

Comment: I'm not serious (with GNU tar): `tar --remove-files -c f??.txt | tar -xv --transform 's|f\(.\)\(.\)|d\1/f\2|' --show-transformed-names`

Comment: Again, you created `d4 /`, not `d4/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

removed unnecessary ";"

```
#! /bin/bash                                                               
for i in {0..9}
do
 mkdir -p "d$i"
 for j in {0..9}
 do
    if [ -e "./f$i$j.txt" ]
    then
        echo 'Moving!'
        mv "./f$i$j.txt" "./d$i/f$j.txt"
    fi
    done
done
```